# How to clear local storage after logout using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have this code

```
var editBtn = document.getElementById('editBtn');
var editables = document.querySelectorAll('#content');

if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {


    if (localStorage.getItem('content') !== null) {
        editables[0].innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('content');
    }
}


editBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (!editables[0].isContentEditable) {
        editables[0].contentEditable = 'true';

        editBtn.innerHTML = 'Save Changes';
        editBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#6F9';
    } else {
        // Disable Editing
        editables[0].contentEditable = 'false';

        // Change Button Text and Color
        editBtn.innerHTML = 'Enable Editing';
        editBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#F96';
        // Save the data in localStorage 
        for (var i = 0; i < editables.length; i++) {
            localStorage.setItem(editables[i].getAttribute('id'), editables[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
});
```

I need a function(code) in addition to this, which will allow me to save current data which in local storage to database  , and reset the local storage once i login to the A/c with a different user

Comment: i know some people just bind clearing localStorage to onClick in link (visiting that url you will be logout via backend)